# What should we do about all the data destruction and recovery tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a lot of tags that seem fairly redundant. There are a number of posts ([example](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/181719/106285)) discussing data remanence and recovery which seem to be used more or less interchangeably:

[data-recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery)
[data-remanence](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-remanence)
[deletion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletion)
[recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery)

What should we do about this? Is there one particular tag we should use for questions involving data remaining on non-volatile storage media and proper techniques to ensure the data is unrecoverable?

Answer (score 5):

Easy things first: The fourth tag, [recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recovery), is just to broad and should be burninated. Most questions can be retagged with [data-recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) or [account-recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-recovery).

The tags [data-recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) and [deletion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletion) are sides of the same coint - a coin that is called [data-remanance](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-remanance). How these three should be structured is a tricky question.

I see three possibilities:

- Alt #0: Keep it as it is.
- Alt #1: Make [data-remanence](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-remanence) an alias of [data-recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery). Keep [deletion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletion) as it is. Recovery and deletion are two different things. Users searching for answers to a specific problem either wants to recover or delete.
- Alt #2: Make both [data-recovery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery) and [deletion](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deletion) aliases of [data-remanence](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-remanence). It's all the same thing.

I would prefer #1 or #2.

Comment: I don't think #1 is good because [tag:data-recovery] could refer to, say, breaking encryption after data is lost, whereas [tag:data-remanence] is about the physics behind data staying around after being overwritten.

Comment: @forest Would that objection also mean that #2 is bad? Perhaps questions like that needs to be retagged with [tag:encryption] or [tag:decryption] or similar?

Comment: While I can appreciate the desire to optimize the tags, many people asking questions, searching, or following do not have the technical expertise to know some of the terms are redundant. Unless it's causing a real problem, I suggest #1 - leave as is.